# Tiny MCE Editor: Create preset blocks of text to insert from toolbar

Tags: javascript, tinymce, config, toolbar

Does anyone know how I create preset blocks of text to insert from a list in the toolbar?

I have an email API that I have integrated with a CMS and an admin can create a new email message to go out using custom tags.  When the CMS detects these custom tags it replaces them with the proper code/links/text, etc. I don't want to have the list of tags beside the editor; rather, I'd prefer there being a dropdown list in the toolbar that has my tags pre-set, kind of like in the CKEditor (if you've used this yet) the custom styles option which I can add/edit through my config.js file.
I hope this makes sense. I couldn't seem to find any results while searching.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is something that isn't even possible?
(every problem should have at least some type solution...)

Comment: Any idea on how this is possible? The 'how' part is why I posted this question.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution will be to write an own tinymce plugin that will wrap the selected text into `pre`-elements that can be replaced serverside. The code would be partial the same as the style plugin that ships with tinymce.

Comment: Thanks for answering Thariama. I will have to look into writing my own plugins then.
Cheers

Comment: make sure you have valid_elements and valid_children set accordingly - so they do not get stripped out